# Improving value hashing

Tags: c++, optimization

Currently I have the following:

```
class Transform
{
    int N; // set in other functions

    std::unordered_map<int,float> cache;

    float Wn(int n)
    {
        std::unordered_map<int,float>::const_iterator got = cache.find(n);
        if(got == cache.end())
        return cache[n] = sin((M_PI / (2 * N)) * (n + 0.5f));

        return cache[n];
}
```

Since the function `Wn` is called a LOT and only the  `n` parameter changes I've tried caching them. My problem is that in many cases the function takes LONGER than without the cache, sometimes even 25% longer. Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input integers are usually in some small range, just use an array as the cache.  Even if some values can't be cached, it will be more efficient than hashing.

Comment: actually they can be in range `SHORT_MIN` to `SHORT_MAX`, and several wont appear at all, so I would be consuming unnecessary RAM. Also, to check if the value was already calculated I'd need another boolean array,  increasing memory taken

Comment: This form of table was used for early computer games, and pre-calculated for all possible values, then just looked up.

Comment: @tofiffe a table with 2^16 entries really isn't that much, you might as well precalculate all of it

Comment: 2^16 is only 65k, hardly anything at all.

Comment: @tofiffe: You don't need a boolean array to know which ones have been computed.  Just fill the array with all 65536 values on startup, or if you don't like that, fill it with NAN and use that as a marker for which inputs aren't cached.

Answer (score 2):

I had a careful look at your code and at what could be done to improve it.

here are 3 annotated versions of the function wN():

Not that it matters in this case (the optimiser takes care of the redundant lookups), there is an arguably more idiomatically correct way to write `Wn()`

first the original version:

```
float original_cached_wN(int n)
{
    // compute hash and search
    std::unordered_map<int,float>::const_iterator got = cache.find(n);
    if(got == cache.end())
        // recompute hash
        // search again
        // default construct 
        // overwrite
        return cache[n] = compute_wN(n);

    // recompute hash
    // search again
    // default construct 
    // overwrite
    return cache[n];
}
```

an idiomatically improved version that takes account of the fact that iterators give us access to the value, which means that we don't need to use the notionally expensive `operator[]`

```
float improved_cached_wN(int n)
{
    // search
    std::unordered_map<int,float>::const_iterator got = cache.find(n);
    if(got == cache.end())
    {
        // emplace the computed value and recover its location
        // from the returned pair<iterator, bool>
        got = cache.emplace(n, compute_wN(n)).first;
    }
    // got is an iterator. got->first is the index, got->second is the value
    return got->second;
}
```

and finally simply compute Wn without caching:

```
float compute_wN(int n) const
{
    return sin((M_PI / (2 * N)) * (n + 0.5f));
}
```

here's a test program that allows a look at the compiled source code resulting from these 3 approaches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class Transform
{

    int N;

    std::unordered_map<int,float> cache;

public:
    Transform(int N) : N(N) {}

    float original_cached_wN(int n)
    {
        std::unordered_map<int,float>::const_iterator got = cache.find(n);
        if(got == cache.end())
            return cache[n] = compute_wN(n);

        return cache[n];
    }

    float improved_cached_wN(int n)
    {
        std::unordered_map<int,float>::const_iterator got = cache.find(n);
        if(got == cache.end())
        {
            got = cache.emplace(n, compute_wN(n)).first;
        }
        return got->second;
    }

    float compute_wN(int n) const
    {
        return sin((M_PI / (2 * N)) * (n + 0.5f));
    }
};



int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // this is to defeat the optimiser
    // and prefent compile-time evaluation of Wn
    std::istringstream ss ("5 4 6 7");
    int N = 10, n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3 = 2;
    ss >> N >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;

    Transform t1(N);
    std::vector<float> v = {
        t1.original_cached_wN(n1),
        t1.improved_cached_wN(n2),
        t1.compute_wN(n3)
    };

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
0.987688, 0.891007, 0.707107,
```

Looking at the compiled output, it actually seems to me that the cost of searching and updating the map outweighs the cost of computing `W(n)`

Here's the code emitted by apple clang 7 for `compute_wN()` after compiling with options `-O3 -march=native`

```
movl    (%rdi), %eax
addl    %eax, %eax
vcvtsi2sdl  %eax, %xmm0, %xmm0
vmovsd  LCPI2_0(%rip), %xmm1    ## xmm1 = mem[0],zero
vdivsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
vcvtsi2ssl  %r15d, %xmm0, %xmm1
vaddss  LCPI2_1(%rip), %xmm1, %xmm1
vcvtss2sd   %xmm1, %xmm1, %xmm1
vmulsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
callq   _sin
```

which to be honest, is a lot less code that the map manipulation.

Comment: It calls `sin` though, it seems you are ignoring that.

Comment: @harold I think you'd have to benchmark the code to understand whether calculating a sine is more expensive in reality than (for example) searching a map that's not in cache.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, your conclusion that's it's "less code".. well maybe, but it has a call in it so that's really a weird conclusion to draw. It could be hiding arbitrarily much code.

Comment: @harold from memory a 64bit pentium takes about 350 cycles to calculate a sin. It will do this with no need to touch any memory.